# Second monitor as second workspace on Cinnamon

Tags: nvidia, cinnamon, multi-monitor, workspaces

I am having an issue with the second monitor attached to my laptop. The monitor appears in Display, can be selected and it does work, but I intend to use it as a different workspace. The nVidia X Server Settings applet won't see the second monitor that is connected through HDMI, even though it appears in the Display applet from Linux Mint. My window manager is Cinnamon.

How can I set my second monitor to a different workspace? Like having 2 different workspaces and 2 different "task bars", because if I am adding a new taskbar now, it just extends the main task bar on my laptop display, and I see all the other apps opened on the taskbar. I just need to have 2 different workspaces on 2 monitors.